# In which language was Stack Overflow written?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What was Stack Overflow built with?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with)

I would like to know which language Stack Overflow was written in.

It's the second website I visit when I start my browser, after Google. It hasn't ever shown me "server too busy" or "server under maintenance." When I think of Google, python comes to mind. Is the same language powering "stacky"?

Comment: Belongs on meta, duplicate on meta. Asked a dozen times. C#/ASP.NET MVC. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with/10370#10370

Comment: It's written in English.

Comment: You close your browser?